# Bootable Linux Flash Drive with USB-C to USB Adapter on a Mac

Tags: linux, boot, mac, usb

I have created a bootable flash linux drive using unetbootin (Debian - Stable netinstall_x64)

I have allowed booting from external or removable media (from Utilities, Startup Security Utility)

I'm running Monterey on my MacBook Pro 2019 (with T2 security chip), and it doesn't accept USB-A, so I had to use a dongle. https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MJ1M2AM/A/usb-c-to-usb-adapter

**Problem**: I'm unable to see this USB drive listed as I restart with the `Option` key pressed down.

I'm not sure if this specific distribution is a problem or if we can't run startup disks if connected through dongles or adapters.

[System Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SJfA.png)

Comment: 2019 Macs have different booting depending on model. What Mac model?

Comment: System info: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nn9rR.png

Comment: Running Linux on a T2 Intel Mac is not simple, but I don't think the dongle is your issue. I have not done it (so no direct help), but this might help: https://wiki.t2linux.org/state/